# Replacing inequality with equality.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, algorithms, numerical-methods, convergence-acceleration

Rate of Convergence:

Definition Let $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ is a sequence that converges to a number $x*$. Suppose that $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ is another sequence known to converge to $0$.

We say $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x*$ with rate of convergence of the sequence ${a_n}$ if there exists a positive constant $K$ such that

$$x_n - x* ≤ K \cdot a_n$$

for  sufficiently large $n$. Normally we take $a_n = 1/n^p$. We are interested in the largest value $p$.

We deduce the following equation from above inequality
$$ lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_n - x*}{a_n}= K$$

On what basis the inequality is converted to equality?
In my book it has been done...

Comment: So that we can obtain the minimum value of K.  further values will surely converge

Comment: On no basis.  There should not be equality.  In fact you cannot even do such division unless $a_n>0$ for all $n$. If $a_n>0$ for all $n$ then we get $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x_n-x^*}{a_n} \leq K$.

Comment: But  it is valid according to book @Michael

Comment: Example 1:  $K=1$, $x_n=x^*=0$,  $a_n=1/n$ for all $n$.   Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (x_n-x^*)/a_n=0 \neq K$.  Example 2: $K=1$, $x^*=0$, $a_n=1/n$ for all $n$, $x_n=1/n$ if $n$ is odd, $x_n=1/n^2$ if $n$ is even. Then $(x_n-x^*)/a_n$ has no limit.

Comment: @Archis Welankar would you.elaborate your comment please!

Answer (score 0):

First,  we should write $|x-x_n|\leq K |a_n|,$ not $x-x_n\leq K a_n.$ For if $x<x_n$ for every $n,$ then $x-x_n<0\leq  K a_n$ for any $K>0$ and any non-negative sequence $a_n$, which tells us nothing about the rate of convergence of $x_n$.

Second, we cannot deduce that $(x_n-x)/a_n$ has a limit, and it usually doesn't. For example, let $x=x_n=1$ when $n$ is even, and  let $x_n=1+1/(1+n)$ when $n$ is odd. Let $a_n=1/(1+n)$ for all $n$ and let  $K=1.$ For even $n$ we have $(x_n-x)/a_n=0$, and for odd $n$ we have $(x_n-x)/a_n=1.$

When $x_n$ and $a_n$ are monotonic the ratio $|(x_n-x)/a_n| $  will still generally fail to converge.

Third, for rates of convergence, it doesn't matter what the values of $x_n$ are for any given finite collection of $n$. So  it is equally useful if $|x-x_n|\leq K|a_n|$ for all but finitely many $n.$

Comment: If we have this form as you suggested $|x-x_n|\leq K|a_n|$  and $a_n$ always of the form $1/n^p$ then we are allowed?

Comment: Allowed to conclude that $(x_n-x)/a_n$ has a limit? NO. Let $x=0.$ Let $x_n=1/n^p$ when $n$ is odd, and $x_n=0$ when $n$ is even..... Not even when $x_n$ is monotonic:  For $j!<n\leq (j+1)!$ let $x_n=1/(j+1)!^p$ with $x=0$ and $K=1.$ All we know is that $x_n$ converges (to within a factor $K$) as fast or faster than $a_n$.